# Storing day-time in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-calendar, android-datepicker

I want to store a certain day and time into SQLite database and retrieve it if it equals day. For example selecting "Monday" from a spinner list and 9:00AM also in another spinner. How will I store Monday 9:00AM if its stored in the same column and only retrieve it every monday forever until it gets deleted from the database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all u need to store value of date and time combine in one column in sql lite.

after that you need to call set alarm manager for particulate time see here for more [details](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: How would I store it into a database though, how will it know its e.g. Monday do i use getDay?